# Implementing isempty function on a QueueAsAStack that privately inherits a LinkedStack

Tags: c++

For this project, we need to create a queue that is a Linked Stack. I am having trouble implementing the isEmpty function for this queue.

QueueAsAStack.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE_AS_A_STACK
#define QUEUE_AS_A_STACK

#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "LinkedStack.cpp"



template<class ItemType>

class QueueAsAStack : public QueueInterface <ItemType>, private LinkedStack <ItemType> {

public:



    bool isEmpty() const;

    bool enqueue(const ItemType&);

    bool dequeue();

    ItemType peekFront() const;

    };



    #endif
```

QueueAsAStack.cpp

```
//Function to check if the Queue is empty

 template<class ItemType>

bool QueueAsAStack<ItemType>::isEmpty() const {


return stack->peek()  == 0;

}
```

Any Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow :) Could you please tell us what "having trouble" means? When asking "why isn't this working" or similar questions, it's good to include: 1.) your code (which you have, great :)) 2.) what you *want* the code to do, exactly, and 3.) what you've tried so far, and how it has not met the requirements of 2.)

Answer (score 0):

I think we are in the same class. If you get anywhere let me know. For isEmpty we used the linked stack's isEmpty method as follows, "return LinkedStack::isEmpty();", inside the isEmpty method for QueueAsAStack.

Comment: Yes I ended up changing that, now I just need to figure out the peekFront implementation and hopefully it will work.

Comment: @DillonTwining currently we are trying to figure out how to get the priority queue class working with the enqueue in queue class since that enqueue is pushing in from the bottom of the stack when the priority queue needs pushed in from the top.